# how are stored procedure inserted/uploaded into database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a stored procedure I've created for postgres. The app I'm developing has backend done in `node` and I've got to upload the stored procedure to our dev server. By upload I just mean to persist that stored procedure in the dev server by executing the `CREATE PROCEDURE...` .

How is this process usually done? I mean, I could just copy the code and paste it on our dev's `pgadmin` and that would work. But, creating a `migration` file for that would also work. Also, executing a `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` raw query inside the code itself would also work.

How is the process of uploading a stored procedure on a postgres running server usually done?

Comment: I would suggest some sort of change management process. Personally I use [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) as it is not framework dependent.

Comment: Migrations are the most common practice, since you can possibly apply them to different databases, and also check them into source control.

Answer (score 1):

There's no definite consensus on this. I've written a console task to do that in a PHP application to apply it, and with hindsight I think that was the wrong choice.

I quite often make other non-structural changes, such as updating or deleting existing records, in a migration, and that is the method I would be inclined to use now.